# How to implement Redis's features with some other datastore?

Tags: perl, nosql, full-text-search, redis

I found [Redis](http://redis.io/) have so good features for my project (webapp's autocomplete back-end). Basicly, it is my fulltext search engine. Now i am looking a replacement for Redis, because i can't hold whole dataset in memory.

I create my Redis store like this (can't find the link for credits for this idea):

1. i chunk my (weighted) items from regular database into 3 char chunks after each char ("words" -> `['wor', 'ord', 'rds']` )
2. every chunk becomes a key to hold sorted list of item's id-s which had such chunk. ( `ZADD chunk weight items_id` )
3. every item id is also key to hold some simple JSON document about item ( `SET items_id items_hash_in_json` )

Search works like this:

1. query string is made same way into 3 char chunks
2. i ask intersection of all those chunks and get list of items_id-s ( combination of `ZINTERSTORE` and `ZRANGEBYSCORE` )
3. return list of JSON docs by items_id-s

Plain and simple. Very effective and fast. There are some smaller cons still in such flow, but mostly i feel having just right tools and right datatypes for my domain.

Main problem is: it requires too much memory. I have about 600K items in database and on 'indexing' i cut them down after 40 chars, but it takes still 2.5GB RAM. It is a bit much for the task. And dataset will grow, not too much and too fast, but still.

I have looked some NoSQL stores now and i have not met similar approach and tools as Redis has. Maybe it is because i look hammer for every work now, but i feel that with other NoSQL stores i need to implement myself such functionalities ( sorted lists, find intersection of them, simple key-value as binary strings, inserting data dead simple, simple protocol/API and simple clients ).

I'd like to have Perl binding too, but in case of very simple protocol (like REST for CoachDB) it is not mandatory.

Do you know such tools to implement my solution with other NoSQL product?

With other eye i already look for completly different solutions too (like [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene), but i'd like to avoid abandon system i described above.

Comment: Of course it's not an answer, but maybe it's better to get more RAM as it's relatively cheap nowadays and 2.5G is not so much (I suppose 8G should be enough for some time). On the other side, you'll lose _Very effective and fast_ if you move to magnetic storage, is it worth? .. and just a simple idea: use a bigger `swap` or similar technology and your RAM will be extended over HDD keeping the functionality of Redis (anyway you want to move to HDD).

Comment: @ArtM: yes, increasing memory is main course now, but if i now pay about 45€ for all my VPS, then for every extra GB i will pay additional 10€ and this does not sound reasonable for such small feature :)

Comment: all depends on how important is this feature, how much profit it generates and how much you are ready to pay ... almost everything has a price in this life :)  ... also try to contact your hoster, maybe they can offer a special VPS without CPU power and storage, but increased RAM

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP Cache**
I have a possible solution for you that I currently use on my site.  I cache autocomplete queries with static files using Nginx.  Nginx can serve static files very quickly.  Here is a sample lines I have in my config.

```
http {

    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2
            keys_zone=tt:600m
            inactive=7d max_size=10g;

    fastcgi_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/tmp;

}
```

This block describes that path where the files will be stored.  levels is how many directories deep, 1:2 would suffice.  My zone here is called tt, name it whatever you want.  Followed by expiration time.

```
location ~ /tt/(.+)\.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

                #Caching parameters
                fastcgi_cache tt;

                fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

                fastcgi_cache_valid  200 302 304 30m;
                fastcgi_cache_valid  301 1h;
                fastcgi_cache_valid  any 5m;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500;
        }
```

The location block will that contains the cache params.  So anything with the URI /tt/.*.php will be cached.  The URI + query string will become the cache key.

If you don't use Nginx, the same concept might work with another webserver.  I hope this helps.

**Edit**

From Comments:
*Using index as plain files seems rather slower than SQL queries. Still, i have not benchmarked them.*

A cache hit for Nginx will look something like this:

> -> Nginx -> file

Miss:

> -> Nginx -> php/python/ruby -> db(redis/mysql/whatever)

The first path might seem slower because you think of diskio, but it's not, the OS will automatically cache files that are frequently accessed.  So when Nginx heats up, just hitting your PHP backend to say "Hello world" is going to be slower in comparison.  I make that claim because it's just like serving a static file.

Actual hit/miss rates will depend on the application, data, and configuration.  In my experience, people use a lot of the same search terms, so you probably won't have 600k files sitting around.  Even if you do it doesn't really hurt, Nginx manages them for you.  This method isn't very good if your data changes a lot and you want the search to reflect those changes quickly.  You would have to set a short expire time which would result in more misses.

**Redis Zip Lists/Hashes**
http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

If you still need sorted sets, make sure the configuration settings from the link are set high enough for your dataset needs.  If you are able to use hashes, you can save a ton of memory using the algorithm they show lower on that page.  I think you can definitely use it to when storing the item_id linking to a json string.

Comment: Do you mean i should use plain files for my index too? Seems rather slow to me to manage more than 600K files. I use Redis now for results caching too and this does not need too much memory, but is very efficient.

Comment: @w.k: so how do you intend to achieve the same efficiency level while rejecting the RAM storage? of course anything else will be rather slow to you if comparing to RAM speeds

Comment: @ArtM: i'm looking for middle ground between Redis solution and using simple query from SQL `SELECT item_id FROM table WHERE description LIKE '%$chunk%'`. Using index as plain files seems rather slower than SQL queries. Still, i have not benchmarked them.

Comment: I updated my post.  I missed the part where you are using Perl.  I'm unfamiliar with using it as a fastcgi backend.

Comment: I also added a bit about redis zipmap/lists.  I use both of these methods in production.

Comment: @MatthewScragg: Memory optimization was good hint! After changing to `zset-max-ziplist-entries 25000`and `zset-max-ziplist-value 10` i reduced memory usage by half. I have about 58k entries max, so 25000 seemed good for beginning. I will try other options too, CPU is much cheaper for me, so zipped sorted list is like a pretty good way here.

Comment: About nginx caching. Yes, as caching engine it may work pretty well, but as autocomplete backend i don't see here solution. When i save all my index into files i need still implement INTERSECTION mechanism to find right answer for my queries. I don't look for caching (Redis handles it pretty well and holding it in memory is pretty cheap), i am looking for fast fulltext quering.

Comment: I would suggest using fulltext index if you use SQL already.  If you don't want to do that.  I can also suggest Elasticsearch which is something I use.  It can potentially be a memory hog but I use it for fulltext searching with 1 million+ forum posts.  It will manage the data for you and not have the entire set in memory.  You can decide to  cache the result with HTTP after ES spits out the results from the query.

Comment: @MatthewScragg: pending from nature of my language (Estonian) English-based fulltext searching does not work for me smoothly. If i had stemmer available, it would be still option. Also, MySQL fulltext is using b-tree, so all searches are based on beginning of the word, which is not good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just asimple idea that could be useful for you. It's not a direct and exact answer to your question.

I suppose that most of your data or a significant part is located in those JSON documents. In this situation I suggest you to change slightly your data infrastructure: in order to keep all the benefits of Redis, you should use the same first 2 steps for *create* and *search*, but change your 3rd step. Instead of using Redis to store these JSON documents, just move them to a simple indexed table of your prefered/used DB. This way you'll handle just the chunks and keys and perform the operations offered by Redis, but at step 3 you take the list of item_id's and retrieve the JSON data from your DB. Probably a `SELECT ... WHERE item_id IN(...)` will be enough.

Comment: JSON docs in Redis take just about 5% of whole memory range, index size is about 2.4GB, while JSON docs take 0.1-0.2 GB.

Comment: @w.k: well, in this case you should use RAM memory if you want speed; even if you would use a DB or something similar, it would have to cache indexes in memory for achieving performance